# Group by region and date using Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, grouping

[image: temp.csv]

I have a  csv file , please check the image for the sample input csv  and I need to get a dataframe that has the sum of the "Amazon Elastic compute cloud" services running on a particular "Availability zone"  group it based on the date.

Something like this

```
|UsageStartDate| AvaliabilityZone  | Sum of products used |  Total cost for each
 
[6/1/16,  ap-northeast-1a, Amazon Elastic compute cloud = 6, 15$]
[6/2/16,  ap-southeast-2 , Amazon Elastic compute cloud = 3,   12$]
```

This is how i tried using pandas :

```
funk = pd.read_csv('/tmp/temp.csv')
funk.sort_values('UsageStartDate') 
k = funk['AvailabilityZone'][funk['ProductName'] == 'Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud'].sum()
print  k
```

Any help on this?

Here is the data:

```
    ProductName               AvailabilityZone  UsageStartDate  BlendedCost
0   Amazon Simple Queue Service                   6/1/16 0:00       0
1   Alexa Web Information Service                 6/1/16 0:00       0.00347032
2   Amazon DynamoDB        ap-southeast-2          6/1/16 0:00      0
3   Amazon DynamoDB        ap-southeast-2          6/1/16 0:00      0
4   Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud    ap-northeast-1a 6/1/16 0:00     0.1
5   Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud    ap-northeast-1a 6/1/16 0:00     0.02
6   Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud                     6/1/16 0:00    0
7   Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud                     6/1/16 0:00    0
8   Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud                     6/1/16 0:00    4.70E-06
9   Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud                     6/1/16 0:00    8.00E-08
10  Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud                     6/1/16 0:00    0.00133333
11  Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud                     6/1/16 0:00    0.005
12  Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud    ap-southeast-1a 6/1/16 0:00     0.02
13  Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud    ap-southeast-1a 6/1/16 0:00     0.02
14  Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud    ap-southeast-1b 6/1/16 0:00     0.02
15  Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud                    6/1/16 0:00     0
```

Comment: You should look at `pandas.groupby`. And when you ask a quesiton, plese include a chunk of sample data that can be copied and pasted to verify the example- NOT an image

Comment: Thanks i'm looking groupby in pandas now.  I have added the data now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) - size by `len` of column `AvailabilityZone` and [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) od column `BlendedCost`:

```
print (df.groupby(['UsageStartDate', 'AvailabilityZone', 'ProductName'])
         .agg({'AvailabilityZone':len,
               'BlendedCost':sum}))
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {
    'ProductName': ['ASQS', 'AWIS', 'AWIS', 'AECC', 'AECC'], 
    'UsageStartDate': ['6/1/16','6/1/16','6/1/16','6/1/16','6/1/16'],
    'AvailabilityZone':['ap-northeast-1a','ap-northeast-1a','ap-northeast-1a','ap-southeast-2','ap-southeast-2'],
    'BlendedCost':[1,2,3,4,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
print (df)
  AvailabilityZone  BlendedCost ProductName UsageStartDate
0  ap-northeast-1a            1        ASQS         6/1/16
1  ap-northeast-1a            2        AWIS         6/1/16
2  ap-northeast-1a            3        AWIS         6/1/16
3   ap-southeast-2            4        AECC         6/1/16
4   ap-southeast-2            5        AECC         6/1/16

print (df.groupby(['UsageStartDate', 'AvailabilityZone', 'ProductName'])
         .agg({'AvailabilityZone':len,'BlendedCost':sum})
         .rename(columns={'AvailabilityZone':'Sum of products used', 'BlendedCost':'Total'})
         .reset_index())

  UsageStartDate AvailabilityZone ProductName  Sum of products used  Total
0         6/1/16  ap-northeast-1a        ASQS                     1      1
1         6/1/16  ap-northeast-1a        AWIS                     2      5
2         6/1/16   ap-southeast-2        AECC                     2      9
```

Solution with sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""ProductName;AvailabilityZone;UsageStartDate;BlendedCost
Amazon Simple Queue Service;;6/1/16 0:00;0
Alexa Web Information Service;;6/1/16 0:00;0.00347032
Amazon DynamoDB;ap-southeast-2;6/1/16 0:00;0
Amazon DynamoDB;ap-southeast-2;6/1/16 0:00;0
Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud;ap-northeast-1a;6/1/16 0:00;0.1
Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud;ap-northeast-1a;6/1/16 0:00;0.02
Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud;;6/1/16 0:00;0
Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud;;6/1/16 0:00;0
Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud;;6/1/16 0:00;4.70E-06
Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud;;6/1/16 0:00;8.00E-08
Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud;;6/1/16 0:00;0.00133333
Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud;;6/1/16 0:00;0.005
Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud;ap-southeast-1a;6/1/16 0:00;0.02
Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud;ap-southeast-1a;6/1/16 0:00;0.02
Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud;ap-southeast-1b;6/1/16 0:00;0.02
Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud;;6/1/16 0:00;0"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=";", index_col=None

#print (df)
```

```
print (df.groupby(['UsageStartDate', 'AvailabilityZone', 'ProductName'])
         .agg({'AvailabilityZone':len,'BlendedCost':sum})
         .rename(columns={'AvailabilityZone':'Sum of products used', 'BlendedCost':'Total'})
         .reset_index())

  UsageStartDate AvailabilityZone                   ProductName  \
0    6/1/16 0:00  ap-northeast-1a  Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud   
1    6/1/16 0:00  ap-southeast-1a  Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud   
2    6/1/16 0:00  ap-southeast-1b  Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud   
3    6/1/16 0:00   ap-southeast-2               Amazon DynamoDB   

   Sum of products used  Total  
0                     2   0.12  
1                     2   0.04  
2                     1   0.02  
3                     2   0.00
```

Comment: I have added the data now

Comment: Thank you. How does solution work? Is necessary use your sample data?

Comment: Ok, I add solution with sample data. Please check it.

Comment: Thank yo so much for your answer, i have another parameter also to consider and i am working on that, sorry for the late reply though
Some of the products doesn't have the Availability zones and they are  notconsidered in the data frame .  
So i need to also consider that  the product names that doesn't have the Availability zones will fall under the last represented zone .

Comment: For ex :  
`5   Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud    ap-northeast-1a  6/1/16 0:00     0.02
6   Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud                               6/1/16 0:00    0
7   Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud                               6/1/16 0:00    0
8   Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud                                6/1/16 0:00    4.70E-06`
 


rows 6,7,8 should also fall under the same region " ap-northeast-1a"

Comment: Ok, if there are `NaN` values, you can convert them to empty strings before `groupby` code: `df['AvailabilityZone'] = df.AvailabilityZone.fillna('')`

Comment: Nope its not about "NaN"  , i was wondering how do i also consider the  the products that doesn't have a zones will fall under the last represented zone

Comment: Ok, in rows with `Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud` missing values are first `ap-southeast-1a` and last value in sample is `ap-southeast-1b`.What is expected values in first and second row in column `AvailabilityZone` ?

Comment: Ok, in my data, you can observe that rows 6,7,8,9,10 and 11 doesn't have a **AvailabilityZone**  .  So we also need to consider that they all fall under the last recent zone  .  In this case   **ap-northeast-1a**  which is row 5 .  Am i making myself clear ?

Comment: Yes, it is clear, but what about row 0 and 1? there is not last values - all values are missing.

Comment: But it seems you can use `df['AvailabilityZone'] = df.AvailabilityZone.ffill()`, but first and second row has still `NaN` values, because no data above it.

Comment: We should not considering those 2 services  while grouping .  Exempt  "Amazon Simple Queue Service" and  "Alex Web service"

Comment: You need remove these rows before grouping? If yes, use `df['AvailabilityZone'] = df.AvailabilityZone.ffill()
df = df.dropna(subset=['AvailabilityZone'])`

Comment: You are the best !  Thanks for the help

Comment: Quick help : How can i get the count of products for a particular date :  

`df.groupby(['UsageStartDate', 'ProductName']).agg({'ProductName':count, 'BlendedCost':sum})`

I grouped date and Product name and and aggregated the above way is this right way

Comment: I dont understand - what is wrong with your code? You need groupby only by `UsageStartDate` ?

Comment: We changed the requirement and wrote another code where and I need to group by 'UsageStartDate' and 'ProductName'  and i should able to get the count of prodcutNames based on UsageStartDate.

For ex:  'Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud'  product is present on  6/1/16 0:00 for 3 times . So i wanted to get the count like :

` 6/1/16 0:00 :  Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud  :  3 `

Comment: Ok, but is something wrong with `df.groupby(['UsageStartDate', 'ProductName']).agg({'ProductName':count, 'BlendedCost':sum})` ? Or you need `df.groupby(['UsageStartDate']).agg({'ProductName':count, 'BlendedCost':sum})` ?

Comment: I tried count but it seems global name 'count' is not defined is what i got everytime

Comment: `df.groupby(['UsageStartDate' ]).agg({'ProductName':len,'BlendedCost':sum})`  

This actually dosen't give you what is the product type , rather it just counts it.  But if i group the product type as well , then i see a wrong count.

 `df.groupby(['UsageStartDate', 'ProductName']).agg({'ProductName':len, 'BlendedCost':sum})`

Comment: I think without data and desired output it is very problematic find solution. Can you create new question with input data, desired output and describe what is problem? the best is use (maybe modify) this sample : `raw_data = {
    'ProductName': ['ASQS', 'AWIS', 'AWIS', 'AECC', 'AECC'], 
    'UsageStartDate': ['6/1/16','6/1/16','6/1/16','6/1/16','6/1/16'],
    'AvailabilityZone':['ap-northeast-1a','ap-northeast-1a','ap-northeast-1a','ap-southeast-2','ap-southeast-2'],
    'BlendedCost':[1,2,3,4,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)`

Answer (score -2):

Here's the docs on the [general aggregation framework for pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) and the [pandas.groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function specifically

```
funk.groupby(['AvailabilityZone','Date','ProductName'])['BlendedCost'].sum()
```